# Conflicting jQuery? Uncaught TypeError in easing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, easing

I'm new to jQuery and I'm using quite a few libraries. I believe they are conflicting because I'm getting an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'undefined' of object #<Object> is not a function                    jquery.easing.1.3.js:46
jQuery.extend.swing jquery.easing.1.3.js:46    
rr.run jquery.min.js:6
l jquery.min.js:6
x.fx.timer jquery.min.js:6
er jquery.min.js:6
a jquery.min.js:6
x.extend.dequeue jquery.min.js:5
(anonymous function) jquery.min.js:5
x.extend.each jquery.min.js:4
x.fn.x.each jquery.min.js:4
x.fn.extend.queue jquery.min.js:5
x.fn.extend.animate jquery.min.js:6
(anonymous function) jquery.colio.min.js:8
x.extend.each jquery.min.js:4
c.insideMakeGap jquery.colio.min.js:8
(anonymous function) jquery.colio.min.js:8
(anonymous function) jquery.colio.min.js:8
```

This happens when I hover over an image and press "View Project". It's supposed to trigger a drop down.

I call the main jQuery library twice, but if I remove one or the other everything breaks. Can someone please help me organize all this jQuery so that everything works?
http://stephmilovic.com/WTF/

I also have the project on github: https://github.com/stephmilovic/WTF

EDIT - Here is all my Javascript

```
<!-- VENDOR JS
================================================== -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- PLUGINS
  ================================================== -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.scrollUp.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.colio.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/waypoints.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/waypoints.min.js"></script>  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="css/colio-black/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js"></script> 
 <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.lazylinepainter-1.4.1.min.js"></script> 

<!-- CUSTOM SCRIPT
================================================== -->

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

      // "scrollTop" plugin 
      $.scrollUp();


      // "colio" plugin
      $('.portfolio .list').colio({
        id: 'demo_1',
        theme: 'black',
        placement: 'inside',
        hiddenItems: '.isotope-hidden',
        onContent: function(content){
          // init "fancybox" plugin
          $('.fancybox', content).fancybox();
        }
      });

      // "isotope" plugin
      var filter = '*', isotope_run = function(f) {
        $('.portfolio .list').isotope({layoutMode : 'fitRows', filter: f}).
        trigger('colio','excludeHidden');
      };

      $('.portfolio .filters a').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('filter-active').siblings().removeClass('filter-active');
        var href = $(this).attr('href').substr(1);
        filter = href ? '.' + href : '*';
        isotope_run(filter);
        return false;
      });

      isotope_run(filter);

    });
  </script>


<script type="text/javascript"> 

      (function( $ ){  

        /* 
        * Lazy Line Painter 1.4
        * SVG Stroke animation.
        *
        * https://github.com/camoconnell/lazy-line-painter
        *
        * Copyright 2013 
        * Cam O'Connell - http://www.camoconnell.com  http://www.behance.net/camoconnell 
        * Released under the MIT license
        *  
        */


        // Define object containing your Raphael path data.
        // goto http://lazylinepainter.info to convert your svg into a svgData object.
        var pathObj = {
          "create2": {
            "strokepath": [
              {
                "path": "M280.9,127.044h-34.049h-5.677v5.667v9.208L59.584,95.873v-7.084L161.729,49.12v4.249v5.667h5.674h34.049  h5.674v-5.667V19.366v-5.667h-5.674h-34.049h-5.674v5.667v17.708L59.584,77.098v-1.064v-5.666H53.91H19.862h-5.677v5.666v34.003  v5.671h5.674h34.049h5.673v-5.666v-2.479l181.594,46.047v8.501l-111.721,78.273H99.307h-5.674v5.669v34.004v5.666h5.674h34.048  h5.674v-5.666v-32.237l107.112-75.441h0.711H280.9h5.674v-5.666V132.71v-5.667H280.9z M173.078,25.035h22.7v22.667h-22.7V25.035z   M48.234,104.374H25.536V81.706h22.698V104.374z M127.681,274.39h-22.698v-22.668h22.698V274.39z M275.223,161.047h-22.698v-22.668  h22.698V161.047z",
                "duration": 1300
             }
              ],
              "dimensions": {
                  "width": 300,
                  "height": 300
              }
            }
          };  

$.noConflict();
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('.thing').waypoint(function() {
         //  Setup your Lazy Line element.
         //  see README file for more settings
            $('#create2').lazylinepainter( 
              {
                  "svgData": pathObj,
                "strokeWidth": 2,
                 "strokeColor": "#444444"
              }).lazylinepainter('paint'); 

              }, {triggerOnce: true})
            });

           })( jQuery ); 

</script>
```

Comment: Are you able to add some of your code that calls this plus any libraries you are calling.

Comment: make sure you place all your custom js code AFTER your jquery include.

Comment: to clarify you might be confused about how the document loads content. 1. you should load your scripts in the footer of the page(page loads top to bottom)
2. you should do vendor code(jquery) then plugins then custom scripts top to bottom.
once you do this it may end up fixing your issue. It might also "break" other stuff but this is the proper way to load scripts according to the JS community. 
when ever i see that error it usually means there is a syntax error in your custom scripts. That or you are initializing some code before other dependency code has loaded.

Comment: @ParkerHutchinson I put my js in what I believe to be the right order right above the </body> tag and it broke everything. Could you please take a look and let me know what I did wrong? I put the code in my original post above

Comment: we cant really know what is happening without seeing an example on here. First thing i would remove all other jquery includes except the one on line 2 of the post above. additionally you only need one document ready [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/QZm6t/1/)

Comment: Ok @ParkerHutchinson, I did what you said and it fixed the animated SVG and the scrollup button, but the drop down still isn't working. Now I'm getting a syntax error for an unrecognized expression, a div class. But it saysthe error is coming from the jquery? So confused. Is the [link to my site](http://stephmilovic.com/WTF/) with all this code on here not good enough of an example? What else can I do, it seems like a pretty good way to share this rather than putting everything in a jsfiddle